# php date + time conversion

Tags: php, date, datetime

i would to know how can i parse date and time which we choose from date time picker into standard `date('YmdHis')` type of results?

```
$datetime = date('YmdHis);
```

[image]

eg date picker return result  `11/13/2012` and time picker result is `2.30 AM`, now i need to know how to joining them together and convert it to `20121113023000` format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo date("YmdHis",strtotime('11/13/2012 2.30 AM'));
```

or

```
    $data = $_POST['date_picker']." ".$_POST['time_picker'];
    echo date("YmdHis",strtotime($data));
```

this will output that in required format

outputs

```
20121113023000
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
 $datatime = date('YmdHis',strtotime($_POST['datepickerfield']));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("11/13/2012 2.30 AM"));
```

outputs

```
2012-11-13 02:30:00
```